# How can I set PHP 7x 64 bit FastCGI in Azure?

Tags: azure, 64-bit, php-7

It seems some error that comes when the traffic increases with a PHP 32-bit [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) setup in Azure.

How can I configure 64-bit PHP 7.x version in Azure?

Comment: Re *"some error"*: Can you be more specific (respond by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60965408/edit), not here in comments)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I applied some caching mechanisms as well and it is satisfying the current traffic.